# Connecting to AWS IOT using Custom Authorizer and use MQTT Username Password

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I want to connect to AWS IOT using username and password and send data on topic. I read about it on AWS IOT documentation that we can achieve this using Custom Authentication:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-authentication.html

I followed the documentation and :

1. Created Custom Authentication Lambda
2. Created Custom Authorizer in AWS IOT using Lambda ARN
3. Added Custom Authorizer to invoke the lambda function.
4. Tested Custom Authorizer using `aws iot test-invoke-authorizer`

I was able to test the lambda with aws int test-invoke-authorizer for MQTT context.

But when I try to connect/publish to AWS IOT using username password It fails. I followed as per below documentation.

[image: Connection to MQTT using username password]

Here is the command which I use to connect AWS IOT using mosquito.org cli

```
 mosquitto_pub -p 443 -i 'sample'  -h XXXXXXXXXX.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com -u "username?x-amz-customauthorizer-name=my-new-authorizer" -P "dGVzdA==" -t test/hello -m "Hello World" -d
```

The error which I received is following

```
Client sample sending CONNECT
Error: Unknown error.
```

NOTE: I am not passing token and signature as mentioned in the documentation as I have disabled it in lambda.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using the AWS sdks? At least you can find out whether the problem is with using mosquitto for the connection or with the passed values themselves.

Comment: Thank you @stijndepestel but I have devices which are low powered and with proprietary os installed by vendors. The reason where I cannot use SDK. I got reply from Amazon Premium support which I have mentioned here.

Comment: Hey @KunalD. can you please help me with the #3 i.e. how you added a custom authorizer? please check [Token key name cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73018951/aws-iot-token-key-name-for-authorizer-mqtt-authorizer-cannot-be-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got reply from AWS premium support and as per them we have to include APLN while issuing command. additionally we have to also provide AmazonRootCA1.pem

```
mosquitto_pub -p 443 -i 'sample' -h XXXX-ats.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com -u "username?x-amz-customauthorizer-name=my-new-authorizer" -P "test" -t test/hello -m "Hello World" --tls-alpn mqtt --cafile AmazonRootCA1.pem -d
```

Note: they have suggested following options:

--cafile AmazonRootCA1.pem

--tls-alpn mqtt

You can download cert from this link:

https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem