# AWS IoT Token key name for authorizer mqtt-authorizer cannot be null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-iot

When I fire the following command (to create custom authorizer in AWS IoT) in the CLI as per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_CreateAuthorizer.html) doc,

```
aws iot create-authorizer --authorizer-name mqtt-authorizer
--authorizer-function-arn arn:<arn>
```

it gives the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the CreateAuthorizer operation: Token key name for authorizer mqtt-authorizer cannot be null
```

As per the document the `--token-key-name` is optional

any idea whats going wrong in this case?

Comment: Did you figure it out? If Not, Did you update your AWS CLI or what version of CLI you are using? If it's older please try to update and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you can check as per documentation:

1. Please check if signing is enabled.
2. You can pass `[--signing-disabled | --no-signing-disabled]` parameters

Please read this
[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/config-custom-auth.html#custom-auth-create-authorizer